# {Two's complement} Bit shifting

Tags: bit, bit-shift

I got confused by all this shifting thing since I saw two different results of shifting the same number. I know there are tons of questions about this thing but seems like I still couldn't find what I was looking for (Feel free to post link of a question or a website that could help).

So, first I have seen the number `13` binary like: `001101` (not whole word of bits).
When applied shifting to the left by `2` they hold the last bit (bit for sign probably) and results like `0|10100 = 20`. However on other place I have seen the number `13` represented like: `01101`, and now the `01101<<2` was `0|0100 = 4`. I know shifting left is same as multiplying by the base, however this made me confused. Should i present `13` as `001101` or `01101` and apply shifting.
I think we omit the overflow considering the results.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour seems to be corresponding with integers of length 5 and 
4 (in bits, not counting the sign bit). So it seems overflow is indeed the problem. If it isn't, could you add some context as to where these strange results occur?

Answer (score 0):

`001101`, `01101` and also `1101` and `00001101` and other sizes have equal claim to "being" 13. You can't really say that 13 has one definitive size, rather it is the operation that has a size (which may be infinite, then a left shift never wraps).

So you have to decide what size of shift you're doing, independently of the value you're shifting. Common choices are 32 or 64 bits, but you're certainly not limited to that, although "strange" sizes take more effort to implement on typical machines and in typical programming languages.

The sign is never deliberately kept in left shifts by the way, there is no useful way to do so: forcefully keeping it means the wrapping happens in a really odd way, instead of the usual wrapping modulo a power of two (which has nice properties).

Comment: Yes, I do understand what you are saying. However, lets say I want to shift  `13 - 001101` (6 bits) and shift it by `<< 3`, would the result be `001000` or `101000`

Comment: @MathNewbie `101000` unless you define a new type of left shift that *does* preserve the sign, it might be useful for *something* (which I would be interested to hear about)

Comment: Such a shift would not have the property `(a + b) << k == (a << k) + (b << k)` for example

Comment: I don't know what it could be used for, we are just taught that..
- [Image](http://prnt.sc/eizcvi)
-[Image](http://prnt.sc/eizclt)
@harold

Comment: Well, that's really odd, but if you're being taught that you should probably use it on the exam.. other than that, I've never seen a shift like that in real life.

Comment: Thanks it seems like I will have to ask the teacher about why we use this and what we do exactly !! :D